# Angularjs - ng-change and $scope.$watch fires only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have tried both ng-change as well as $watch on the model. However, it fires exactly once. Either when the first character of the input is entered. Or when the last character is deleted. For example, when I enter the first number, the function is called correctly. When I continue typing other numbers into the input, the function isn't called. Like when the input is "1234", it fires when 1 is typed into the input. But when 2 and 3 and 4 are entered, it does not get fired.

Same thing happens while deleting. When 4,3,2 are deleted, the event doesn't get fired. When 1 is deleted, it gets fired.

I did search the forum before asking. However, I was not able to find any meaningful answer. Does it have anything to $digest lifecycle?

Comment: provide us fiddle or runnable sample to demo your issue

Comment: what you are describing isn't reproducible with default code;  this is likely being caused by something in your code or environment.  a [mcve] of the issue is necessary to understand what might be going on.

Comment: @PandiyanCool It works fine on fiddle.

Comment: @Claies It is proprietary code. So I will not be able to do that. It is something to do with the environment. And since I couldn't find an answer, I asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ng-keyup event, try this bellow

```
<div ng-controller="test">

<input ng-model="a" ng-keyup="check()" />

</div>

  angular.module("myApp", [])
 .controller('test', ['$scope', function($scope){


   $scope.check = function(){
    alert('it changes');
 }
 }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful, if you elaborate your question further more.

Basically this scenario working fine.

```
<div ng-controller="test">

<input ng-model="a" ng-change="check()" />

</div>
```

JS code

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller('test', ['$scope', function($scope){


  $scope.check = function(){
    alert('it changes');
  }
}]);


<div ng-controller="test">

<input ng-model="a" ng-change="check()" />

</div>
```

Comment: I don't think there is anything to add to that. The above fiddle works fine for me too. But not in the context of my application. I have used $watch as well as ng-change before and they both worked.

Answer (score 0):

Today i had the same problem. I'm not sure if your case is/was the same but, the problem for me was that my input's type was email and this fires the change event on first character entered and after that it fires the event again right after you type @ in the string.
What will fire the change event:

- example (will fire it once)
- example@ (won't fire)
- example@a (will fire it again)
- example@a. (will not fire it)
- example@a.c (will fire it again)

Hope that helped :)